# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2(2-x)}(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\sqrt{1-x}(2-\sqrt{4-x^2})}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I use L'Hospitals rule, but can't get the correct limit.
Derivative of numerator in function is
$$\frac{-3x^2+4x-\sqrt{1-x^2}+1}{\sqrt{(4-2x)(1-x^2)}}$$
and derivative of denominator is
$$\frac{-3x^2+2x-2\sqrt{4-x^2}+4}{2\sqrt{(1-x)(4-x^2)}}$$

Now, L'Hospitals rule must be applied again. Is there some easier way to compute the limit?

Limit should be $L=4$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiplying it by $$\frac{{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\cdot\frac{2+\sqrt{4-x^2}}{{2+\sqrt{4-x^2}}}\ (=1)$$gives$$\begin{align}&\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2(2-x)}\ (1-\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\sqrt{1-x}\ (2-\sqrt{4-x^2})}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2(2-x)}\ \color{red}{(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})}}{\sqrt{1-x}\ \color{blue}{(2-\sqrt{4-x^2})}}\cdot\frac{\color{red}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\cdot\frac{2+\sqrt{4-x^2}}{\color{blue}{2+\sqrt{4-x^2}}}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2(2-x)}\ (2+\sqrt{4-x^2})\color{red}{(1-(1-x^2))}}{\sqrt{1-x}\ (1+\sqrt{1-x^2})\color{blue}{(4-(4-x^2))}}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2(2-x)}\ (2+\sqrt{4-x^2})}{\sqrt{1-x}\ (1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}\\&=\frac{\sqrt 4\ (2+\sqrt 4)}{1\cdot (1+1)}\\&=4\end{align}$$

Comment: If someone is working on an answer when you submit yours, it is quite common that the two answers are essentially the same. Please do not assume that they copied yours.

Comment: @martycohen: I agree with your first sentence. But I think this case is not the situation you write because the difference is about 23 minutes. Also, I didn't assume that he copied mine (no one can know if he copied others' answer except himself). Instead, I assumed that he didn't take a look at others' answers before writing an answer, whiich must be true. This is all I've said.

Answer (score 1):

**using Bernoulli** $$x \to 0 \\ {\color{Red}{(1+ax)^n \approx 1+anx} } \\\sqrt{1-x^2} = (1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \approx 1-\frac{1}{2}x^2 \\ \sqrt{4-x^2}=\sqrt{4(1-\frac{x^2}{4}})=2(1-\frac{x^2}{4})^{\frac{1}{2}} \approx 2(1-\frac{1}{2} \frac{x^2}{4})=2-\frac{x^2}{4} $$ so by putting them in limit :
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{2(2-x)} (1-\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\sqrt{1-x}(2-\sqrt{4-x^2})}=\\\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{2(2-x)} (1-(1-\frac{1}{2}x^2))}{\sqrt{1-x}(2-(2-\frac{x^2}{4}))} =\\ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{2(2-x)} (\frac{1}{2}x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x}(\frac{x^2}{4})}=\\\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{2(2-x)} 2}{\sqrt{1-x}}=4 $$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2(2-x)}(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\sqrt{1-x}(2-\sqrt{4-x^2})}\right) = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2(2-x)}(2 + \sqrt{4-x^2})}{\sqrt{1-x}(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}\right) = 4$

Answer (score 0):

First note that the factors $\sqrt {2 (2-x)}$ and $\sqrt {1-x}$ tend to $2$ and $1$ respectively, therefore they don't raise any problem. It remains to compute the limit of $\frac {1 - \sqrt {1-x^2}} {2 - \sqrt {4-x^2}}$. Note that this fraction can be rewritten as $\frac {1 - (1-x^2)} {1 + \sqrt {1-x^2}} \frac {2 + \sqrt {4 - x^2}} {4 - (4-x^2)} = \frac {2 + \sqrt {4 - x^2}} {1 + \sqrt {1-x^2}}$ which clearly tends to $2$. Putting all the pieces together, the limit is $4$.

(The core fact was that $a-b = \frac {a^2 - b^2} {a+b}$.)

Answer (score 0):

For $a>0,$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{a^2-(a^2-x^2)}{x^2(a+\sqrt{a^2-x^2})}=\dfrac1{2a}$$ as $x\ne0$ as $x\to0$

Or set $x=a\sin2y\implies y\to0\implies\sin y\to0$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x^2}=a\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos2y}{(a\sin2y)^2}=\dfrac1a\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos2y}{(2\sin y\cos y)^2}$$

$$=\dfrac1a\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{2\sin^2y}{(2\sin y\cos y)^2}=\dfrac1{2a}$$ as $\sin y\ne0$ as $\sin y\to0$

Answer (score 0):

L'Hopital can be used, but it goes a lot better if you notice one thing: There are garbage terms in there that can be factored out, leaving a much cleaner problem. Here's what I'm talking about:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt {2(2-x)}}{\sqrt {1-x}} = \frac{2}{1}=2.$$

So we can move that junk out of way, and mulitply by $2$ at the end. We're left thinking about

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\sqrt {1-x^2}}{2- \sqrt {4-x^2}},$$

which Monsieur L'Hopital can handle well.